# Products not getting displayed on category page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category, category-products

I have used magento 2.0.2 and i have create many products by manually. but products not display on category page. Also assign in category, website, visibility, stock, and assign Is_anchor yes in category. then clear cache and indexing. can you please suggest me for resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Clear browser cache and check it once again.

Comment: I have already do it

Comment: if I run static content deploy command then it gives this error :- Compilation from source ../source/module.less

How can I resolve it?